# Detect Foundation Small/Large Usage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to detect whether a [Foundation grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) is in "small" or "large" mode using Javascript?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can create a function like this:

```
var isLarge, isMedium, isSmall;

isSmall = function() {
  return matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['small']).matches && !matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries.medium).matches;
};

isMedium = function() {
  return matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['medium']).matches && !matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries.large).matches;
};

isLarge = function() {
  return matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['large']).matches;
};
```

Then call it like this:

```
if (isSmall()) {
  alert("Too small!");
}

if (isLarge()) {
  alert("Too big!");
}

if (isMedium()) {
  alert("Just right!");
}
```

Another way that is not foundation specific:

In your CSS media query for small only (adjust to suit):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {
  body:after {
    content: 'small';
    display: none;
  }
}
```

In your Javascript, use a function to get the content of that element and compare it:

```
var getSize;

getSize = function() {
  return window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');
};
```

In certain browsers, getSize() will return a value that is quoted, so using if (getSize() == "small") does not work. You can get around that by using this to compare:

```
if (getSize().indexOf("small") !== -1) {
  // do something
}
```

Credit to this blog post for this method: http://adactio.com/journal/5429/

Comment: Excellent, found these functions very useful.

Answer (score 3):

The default Foundation5 methods handling media queries available are:

```
// Small queries
Foundation.utils.is_small_only();
Foundation.utils.is_small_up();

// Medium queries
Foundation.utils.is_medium_only();
Foundation.utils.is_medium_up();

// Large queries
Foundation.utils.is_large_only();
Foundation.utils.is_large_up();

// XLarge queries
Foundation.utils.is_xlarge_only();
Foundation.utils.is_xlarge_up();

// XXLarge queries
Foundation.utils.is_xxlarge_only();
Foundation.utils.is_xxlarge_up();
```

See "Media Queries" under http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript-utilities.html.

Comment: easy to use with jQuery's `window.onresize = function(event) {}`

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a better way:

```
if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast('medium')) {
// True if medium or large
// False if small
}
```

more information [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html#javascript).

Comment: Agree, much better. F6 can also use `console.log(Foundation.MediaQuery.current); // 'small', 'large', etc.` and also `if (Foundation.MediaQuery.is('small only')) { // True if small // False if medium or large }` etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Responsive Bootstrap Toolkit](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit) library, which despite its name, works with just any framework, including Foundation. Detecting breakpoints would look like the following for Foundation:

```
(function($, viewport){

    viewport.use('Foundation');

    if( viewport.is('small') ) {
        console.log('Matching: small');
    }

    if( viewport.is('>=medium') ) {
        console.log('Matching: medium, large and xlarge');
    }

    // You can also create a listener with debouncing that will perform an action
    // whenever window size changes.
    $(window).resize(
        viewport.changed(function(){
            console.log('Current breakpoint:', viewport.current());
        })
    );

})(jQuery, ResponsiveBootstrapToolkit);
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of said library.